# what does funtion call stack means in this code ? how does it store something?

Tags: java, stack

```
static void reverse()
{
    if(st.size()>0)
    {
        /* Hold all items in Function Call Stack until we
           reach end of the stack */
        char x = st.peek(); // << This line
        st.pop();
        reverse();

        /* Insert all the items held in Function Call Stack
           one by one from the bottom to top. Every item is
           inserted at the bottom */
        insert_at_bottom(x);
    }
}
```

What does the line with `<< This line` mean in the code? The code was taken from [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/?p=6921).

Comment: It all depends on what class `st` is.

Comment: It is clearly a stack.

Comment: hmm....ya it given in link st is stack

Comment: i understand recursion but doesn't understand how it store values after poped out from stack

Comment: @shikharsingh Values are pushed on the stack as it recurses, and then popped back off the call stack when/as they return.  Each invocation of `reverse()` has its' own `char x`. Understand?

Comment: yeah now i understand .thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this program call stack (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) will look like this if `st` contains (a1, a2, a3, a4):

```
reverse
x = a1
    reverse
    x = a2
        reverse
        x = a3
            reverse
            x = a4
            --> insert_at_bottom(a4)
        --> insert_at_bottom(a3)
    --> insert_at_bottom(a2)
--> insert_at_bottom(a1)
```

As result st will contain (a4, a3, a2, a1) if I undestand `insert_at_bottom` function correctly.

Answer (score -1):

`peek()` looks at the object at the top of this stack without removing it from the stack.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html

Comment: I was answering "What does the line with << This line mean in the code?".